# Facebook Developer Account always disabled after couple of days of using Messenger API

Tags: facebook, messenger

This is not exactly a programming related question but it is closely related to developing so I think it is pertinent.

I´ve been charged in my work with developing an app with access to Facebook Messenger. I needed a Facebook Account and I didn´t want to use a personal one (and I don´t use Facebook anyway) so I created a new gmail account to use it to sign up in Facebook, as user and as a developer.

After a couple of days of work, having created the page, my webhook, done some tests, etc., and investing a good deal of work hours, my account appeared as disabled.

I have to admit a didn´t use much of real info on this account (I´m kind of allergic to disclosing personal information unless mandatory), and the account was new so I thought that maybe that was the reason (they don´t give you any).
So I tried again a second time with an account I had been using for years (just for logging in some sites, not much of real information there neither, as I say I don´t really use Facebook), and after a couple of days, same results, locked account.

I can´t stress enough I don´t use the API extensively, I just send some messages to another user I have added as one of the application developers so I can test (that other account is never blocked, by the way). It´s not like I am sending hundreds of messages or anything like it. And by the way, I have never been blocked while I was doing something (so I could indentify my wrongdoing). It just happened that at some point when I was going back to work (first hour in the morning, or after lunch for example) I tried to log in again and then I got the warning.

So I have tried a third time, this time I have given all my real information, reluctantly uploaded a personal picture, given all my data to Facebook (yikes!).

And after a couple of days: damn, same result. Blocked account. Work lost. They prompt you to upload a picture to check your Id, but to no avail (no answer yet, not even a notice of any kind) and they don´t give you absolutely any reason why the have blocked you.

[image: Facebook Blocked Account Message]

And if I go to https://facebook.com/help/contact/260749603972907 to fill the form where they ask you to upload an ID then it says that the email doesn´t belong to a disabled account!

What is the unusual activity they have detected? What have I done wrong? Has someone experienced the same problem? Has someone got any clue of what it is that I could be doing wrong?

Because I don´t want to go through the whole process once again only to get blocked in a couple of days.

Thanks.

EDIT 1:

Ok, after checking again now it recognizes the account as a disabled one. I have gone to https://facebook.com/help/contact/260749603972907 to fill the form and I have uploaded my ID (even though I completely disagree with disclosing that kind of information).

[image]

Honestly, I don´t know what it means by "shortly". It´s been two days now and I have not received any kind of notification yet.

By the way, I haven´t received any kind of notification (mail, sms, anything) during any step of the process EVER. No one. Nothing. Not even an automatic email response. Plain absolute silence.

Honestly, if Facebook uses a security system like this, that lets hackers in while blocks legitimate users, creating false positives and making us lose many hours of work, without any reason or notification or explanation, then Facebook security is plain wrecked.

And I cannot do anything less than to strongly discourage any developer to use it if they can avoid it (what unfortunately I can´t).

EDIT 2:
After some days I regained access to my account again. Without any notification, I just tried again and now it worked (really good communication policy, Facebook, congratulations).

My App had disappeared, so I had to go through the whole process again. And after sending ONE message to the API, this again:
[image]

And once again the asked me to upload a picture of myself (I think they already have enough pictures of me to make an album).

This is just plain crazy.

Comment: what kind of API access you're using? at which rate? are you abusing the API? It's unclear to tell what's happening.

Comment: If you used a “fake” name or something easily identifiable as made-up gibberish, then you must’n wonder if Facebook blocks it when discovered. You need to use a “real” account that bears your real name, those are simply the rules of the platform.

Comment: And with the recent “scandals” and subsequent measures against, they might be more suspicious of new developer accounts as well, I suppose ... So possible that behavior which would not have gotten you in trouble with an account that already has a “history” and got actively used for a longer period of time, gets you more easily blocked with a fresh account.

Comment: @CBroe as I have stated, I am already using all my real data (name, birthdate, picture, everything) and I have been blocked nonetheless. I am using what can be considered by all means a real account.

Comment: I am using the Messenger API as can be seen in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/#send_api_basics. I am just responding to some messages another user (let´s call it developer 2, where developer 1 would be the one setting up the page/application/webhook) sends to a page. Then my application receives the message in the webhook and responds with some other message. Maybe a couple dozen messages in a hour or so, nothing abusive at all.

Comment: I am trying to create a bot messenger and just faced exactly the same issue. Blocked 3 times. @Ada did you managed to have it working?